# Java (edited) - Why isn't the winner method for my TicTacToe game being acknowledged?

Tags: java, arrays

I completely changed my code for checking a win in rows, columns, and both diagonals but when I run the program, winners are not acknowledged.

This is my method for checking winners, displaying the board, adding a move, switching between players, and restarting. I am having an issue because when I run the program, it won't switch between the players properly.

```
import java.util.*;
public class TicTacToe {
   private char[][] gameBoard = new char[3][3]; //stores the game as a 2D array in which each element is a character
   private char currentMark;
   private Scanner input;
   public TicTacToe() { //initializes the board
      currentMark = 'X';
      for (int i=0; i<3; i++) { //for every row
         for (int j=0; j<3; j++) { //for every column in that row
            gameBoard[i][j] = ' '; //set the value of each element to an empty string
         }

      }
      input = new Scanner(System.in);
   }


   public void whoseTurn() {
      if (currentMark == 'X') {
         currentMark = 'O';
         System.out.println("It is your turn, player O");
      }
      else {
         currentMark = 'X';
         System.out.println("It is your turn, player X");
      }    
   }

   public boolean checkRows() {
      boolean rowWin=false;
      for (int i=0;i<3;i++){ 
         if ((gameBoard[i][0] == gameBoard[i][1]) && (gameBoard[i][1] == gameBoard[i][2]) && (gameBoard[i][0] == currentMark)) { //check every row to find a match
            rowWin= true;
         }
      }
      return rowWin;
   }

   public boolean checkColumns() {
      boolean columnWin=false;
      for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
         if ((gameBoard[0][i] == gameBoard[1][i]) && (gameBoard[1][i] == gameBoard[2][i]) && (gameBoard[0][i] == currentMark)) { //checks every column to find a match
            columnWin= true;
         }
      }
      return columnWin;
   }

   public boolean checkDiag1() {
     boolean diag1win=false;
     for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
         if ((gameBoard[0][0] == gameBoard[1][1]) && (gameBoard[1][1] == gameBoard[2][2]) && (gameBoard[0][0] == currentMark)) { //checks first diagonal
            diag1win= true;
         }
      }
      return diag1win;
   }

   public boolean checkDiag2() {
      boolean diag2win=false;
      for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
         if ((gameBoard[0][2] == gameBoard[1][1]) && (gameBoard[1][1] == gameBoard[2][0]) && (gameBoard[0][2] == currentMark)) { //checks second diagonal
            diag2win= true;   
         }
      }
      return diag2win;
    }

   public boolean checkWinner() {
     boolean yesWinner = false;
     if (checkRows() || checkColumns() || checkDiag1() || checkDiag2()) {
         yesWinner = true;
     }
     return yesWinner;
   }

   public boolean addMove() { 
      boolean nonacceptable = true;
      int row;
      int column;
      while (nonacceptable) {
         System.out.println("Which row and column would you like to enter your mark? Enter the row and column between 0 and 2 separated by a space.");
         row = input.nextInt();
         column = input.nextInt();
         if ((row >= 0 && row <=2) && (column >= 0 && column <=2)) { //make sure user entered a number between 0 and 2
            if (gameBoard[row][column] != ' ') {
               System.out.println("Sorry, this position is not open!");
            }
            else {
               gameBoard[row][column] = currentMark;
               nonacceptable = false;
            }
         }   
         else 
            System.out.println("That position is not between 0 and 2!");
         }
         return nonacceptable;     
   }
   public void restart() {
      for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
         for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
            gameBoard[i][j] = ' ';
         }
      }
   }
   public boolean boardFull() {
      boolean notFull = true;
      for (int i=0; i<3;i++) {
         for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
            if (gameBoard[i][j] != ' ') 
               notFull = false;
         } 
      }
      return notFull;
   }

   public void letsPlay() {
      while (true) {
         displayBoard();
         gameOptions();
         int choice = input.nextInt();
         if (choice == 1) {
            if (!addMove()) {
               if (checkWinner()) 
                  System.out.println(currentMark + "wins!");
               else continue;
               displayBoard();               
               whoseTurn();
               //System.exit(0);
             }


          else if (boardFull()) {
               displayBoard();
               System.out.println("Board full!");
               System.exit(0);
            } 
           else {
               whoseTurn();
            } 
         }
         else if (choice == 2) 
            restart();
         else if (choice == 3) 
            System.exit(0);

        /* else 
            System.out.println("Try again!"); */
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      TicTacToe game = new TicTacToe();
      game.letsPlay();
   }

}
```

Comment: Because `addMove` always returns false?

Comment: @immibis when I change the value of nonacceptable to true, the program still does not run properly and just goes straight to "board full" message

Comment: Can you indent your code properly? It is impossible to read because your indenting conflicts with the actual braces/brackets in your program

Comment: @xson That's irrelevant. You have `if(addMove()) {...stuff here...}`. `addMove` always returns false, therefore `...stuff here...` never executes. You might need to rethink what you want the code to do.

Comment: Removing relevant code is never a good idea. I rolled back your last edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's something wrong within `addMove`. In the while loop, this code means that the move is accepted, and continue.

```
else {
           gameBoard[row][column] = currentMark;
           nonacceptable = false;
        }
```

and then you return `nonacceptable`, which is false. But, your play method is this :

```
if (addMove()) { 
           if (checkWinner()) 
              System.out.println(currentMark + "wins!");
           displayBoard();               
           whoseTurn();
           System.exit(0);
        }
```

As `addMove` return false, it will not get in to the `if`. Better change to this :

```
if (!addMove()) { 
               if (checkWinner()) 
                  System.out.println(currentMark + "wins!");
               displayBoard();               
               whoseTurn();
               System.exit(0);
            }
```

And one more, in the `checkWin`, when you compare the cell, pay attention here, because empty line will return true. You should compare each cell with `currentMark`

Ok, let say after the first move, what do your function check. We look into `checkColumns`, it will return true. Because `gameBoard[0][0]`= `gameBoard[1][0]` = `gameBoard[2][0]` = " ". That's why you should compare with your current mark. You have 2 options, pass the current mark to the function and check it, or make the variable `currentMark` global

The program will not stop, because you didn't do anything to stop it when there's a winner. This should do :

```
if (!addMove()) { 
           if (checkWinner()) {
              System.out.println(currentMark + "wins!");
              //put the code to stop the program here
              //like return or exit
           }
           displayBoard();               
           whoseTurn();
           System.exit(0);
        }
```

---

Look at your output, it seems to me that your `whoseTurn` was never executed. And for the reason why I could not tell. Could you provide more code, especially where your game loop start

And your code has many small problems. In the `checkDiagonal`, I think the `for` loop here is unnecessary, since there are only 1 first diagonal and 1 second diagonal.

---

The problem is that your method `whoseTurn` didn't act as expected. So I need to see how it was called in your code. With this I can't see where's the problem. You could try to debug, put a breakpoint inside `whoseTurn`, or some output, to see if this function is called.

---

So I was wright, it's your game loop, method `letsPlay` which is wrong. In the `if` statement when checking if there's a winner, in the else, the `continue` will make the code return to the `while` immediately, ignore the rest of code. That's why `whoseTurn` is ignored. This should do :

```
public void letsPlay() {
        displayBoard();

        while (true) {
            gameOptions();
            int choice = input.nextInt();
            if (choice == 1) {
                if (!addMove()) {
                    displayBoard();

                    if (checkWinner()){
                        System.out.println(currentMark + "wins!");
                        return;
                    }
                    whoseTurn();
                    // System.exit(0);
                }

                else if (boardFull()) {
                    displayBoard();
                    System.out.println("Board full!");
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    displayBoard();

                    whoseTurn();
                }
            } else if (choice == 2)
                restart();
            else if (choice == 3)
                System.exit(0);

            /*
             * else System.out.println("Try again!");
             */
        }
    }
```

I checked and play good.

Comment: I just changed it like so but then it just prints the board twice and says that the current mark wins.

Comment: You mean that you can only make 2 moves ?

Comment: I can make as many moves as I need to, but the displayBoard prints the board twice continuously and before every new move, it says that the previous mark won.

Comment: Ok i get it. Because, you would have empty line or column or diagonal at the beginning, and `checkWinner` test to see if 3 cells in the same column, row or diagonal match each others. So you should compare to `currentMark` too. And as for why it prints the board 2 times continuously, your provided code can't let us see. Post more code and we get it right

Comment: yeah I think that you should add `currentMark` into `checkWin` : `if ((gameBoard[i][0] == gameBoard[i][1]) && (gameBoard[i][1] == gameBoard[i][2]) && (gameBoard[i][0]==currentMark))`

Comment: I just added the output I am getting. could you please provide the code to fix, I'm a little confused as to what you mean by add currentMark

Comment: notice how above in the update, it says "x wins!" or "o wins!" after every move..and also it displays the board twice. How can I fix this?

Comment: Now I have a few new problems.. updated the winner code above and added the new output. When I ran it this time, the first 3 marks were placed by X because it did not switch the marks like it should've..and then after player x already won, then it switched to player O.

Comment: I updated the code, for stopping when there's a winner. For switching people, I need more code to find out where's the hole in your program. It would be better if you could share your code on Github, and we will see what's wrong

Comment: I added the rest of the code. The only thing I cut out was displayBoard and gameOptions since those were both fine. I'm not sure how to use github...

Comment: It's your `letPlay` method. I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You should consider removing the `boolean` return value on the `addMove()` method, remove the return statement within `addMove()`, change the return value to `void`, and update the play method code to:

```
addMove(); 
if (checkWinner()) {
    System.out.println(currentMark + "wins!");
}
displayBoard();               
whoseTurn();
System.exit(0);
```

Just let the `boolean` within `addMove()` serve as the guard that controls iteration within the `while` loop and I think you will be very close to what you want.